# how to replace part of a string with a double c++

Tags: c++, string, replace, double

I have been searching on stack overflow and the web and cannot seem to find an answer to my question.

*How do you replace part of a string with a variable*

Example: I want to replace the "#N" at the end of this string with the variable 'number'.

**First Attempt:**

```
string firstline= "will find the answer in Chapter #N.";
firstline.replace(firstline.begin(),firstline,end(),"#N",number);
```

turns out the replace function doesn't allow you to pass those as variables.

**Second Attempt:**

I found a youtube tutorial that changed part of a string with another string.

```
string replace_all(string str, const string &from, const string &to)
{
int pos=0;
int flen= from.length();
int tlen = to.length();
while((pos= str.find(from,pos)) != -1)
{
   str.replace(pos,flen,to);
   pos += tlen;
}
return str;
}

int main()
{
char str[] = "will find the answer in Chapter #N."
cout<< replace_all(str, "we", "you"); 
return 0;
}
```

Made some changes to have the 3rd parameter be a double, but I'm still unable to get anywhere with it.

Any help to get me to the correct answer would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
   @sneha made the suggestion that I change the variable to a string using to_string()

I did that suggestion and my code can now compile, however I'm unable to successfully change the string.  The output is still `"will find the answer in Chapter #N."`

```
int main()
{
double number =20;
char str[] = "will find the answer in Chapter #N."
cout<< replace_all(str, "we", to_string(number)); 
return 0;
}

string replace_all(string str, const string &from, const string &to)
{
int pos=0;
int flen= from.length();
int tlen = to.length();
while((pos= str.find(from,pos)) != -1)
{
   str.replace(pos,flen,to);
   pos += tlen;
}
return str;
}
```

Comment: Is there single `#N` in the code? Is it position fixed in the string?

Comment: It's a two step process. Turn the number into a string, then do a string replacement.

Comment: convert the number variable from double to string and then use the replace function.

Answer (score 1):

Change the double variable to string using

```
    std::to_string(c1)
```

Then replace the string with it

**EDIT:**

```
string replace_all(string str, const string &from, const string &to) {
int flen= from.length();
auto val = str.find("#N");
if (val != string::npos) str.replace(val, flen, to);
return str;
}
```

Here npos means no position- string not found.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that allows my code to compile, however when I output the string, it remains unchanged

Comment: In your replace_all function find if  "#N" is present or not in the string, If present then replace the string. See the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string firstline= "will find the answer in Chapter #N.";
    if(firstline.find("#N") != string::npos)
        firstline.replace(firstline.find("#N"), string("#N").size(), to_string(5));
    cout<<firstline<<endl;
    // will find the answer in Chapter 5.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Replace(string& s, double v) {
    auto it = s.find("#N");
    if (it != string::npos) s.replace(it, 2, to_string(v));
}

int main() {
    string firstline = "will find the answer in Chapter #N.";
    Replace(firstline, 12.35);
    cout << firstline << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes that replaces it however what if I want to replace the 12.35 with a variable named number? I can't get it work.

Comment: Are you talking about `double num = 12.35; Replace(firstline, num)`? What is the problem then?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do.  Replace( firstline, num)  however when I execute the program I get still "will find the answer in Chapter #N."

Comment: Have you run my program? Because I am getting the replaced string even when I use `double num = 12.35`.

Comment: How come I cannot increment the variable number down though?

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Replace(string& s, double v) {
 auto it = s.find("#N");
 if (it != string::npos) s.replace(it, 2, to_string(v));
}

int main() {
 int number = 20;
 string firstline = "will find the answer in Chapter #N.";
 Replace(firstline, number);
 cout << firstline << endl;

 number--;
 Replace(firstline, number);
 cout << firstline << endl;

 return 0;
}
outputs:
will find the answer in Chapter 20
will find the answer in Chapter 20

Comment: Because when you first call `Replace` function, the `firstline` changed. There is no `#N` in that string anymore. So for the second time, `Replace` does not find any `#N` in firstline. So there is nothing to replace.